# django's forbidden(403) response when session is expired, how to change it to unauthorized(401)

Tags: django, session, csrf, django-csrf

I am trying to upload a file in an application. I empty my browsing data or somehow end my session and then I hit upload. I select a file from my filesystem and I get a forbidden (403) error from Django's server. csrf.py's code get executed.

```
if not constant_time_compare(request_csrf_token, csrf_token):
                logger.warning('Forbidden (%s): %s',
                               REASON_BAD_TOKEN, request.path,
                    extra={
                        'status_code': 403,
                        'request': request,
                    }
                )
                return self._reject(request, REASON_BAD_TOKEN)
```

Now, that I dont want to change Django's code, how do I present 401 to the user and not 403. I dont want to capture 403 from server and change it to 401 in my Javascript. Any other solutions?? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW) setting allows you to
 write your own view for CSRF failures. You could write one that returns HTTP status 401.